# How to pin Emails+Accounts on the window screen?

Tags: email

I accidentally removed the default emails+accounts pin from the main Windows Screen ( has an envelope as an icon) . Now how do I pin it back to the main Windows screen? The option to pin it is not available. I also do not want to do a hard reset of the phone.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. Did you mange solve this issue ?

Comment: @Hemant : Yes. I switched to Android :)

Comment: @Hemant The answer given by Bilahari Prasad solves this problem.

Answer (score 4):

To pin an individual inbox to the Start Screen you open Outlook mail, click the Hamburger Menu, tap an account which takes you to all accounts, and then tap and hold a specific account to show the option to pin it.

Answer (score 2):

When adding an account, you gave the account a name.

Go to the application list (Windows key, then swipe to the right). On the application list, look for the account name. Long tap the account name and then tap "pin to start".

*Note*: if you don't remember the name given to your account, go to Settings then "emails+accounts" then click on "Microsoft account" and the first field states the account name.

Comment: The account name is not listed in the applications. I have tried renaming the accounts to no avail. I am using Lumia Black update.

Comment: Does the account exist in `Settings` > `emails + accounts`?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. I have a facebook and a hotmail account

Comment: What is the name of the Hotmail account?

Comment: It is called Microsoft Account. I tried renaming it to zzzz. Neither of them showed up on the applications list

Comment: I am having similar issue on my win 10 phone :(

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook Mail app, then select the inbox account you want to pin. When it opens, tap the menu (3 dots) at bottom of screen and you will find an option to "pin to start".